# Pagination goes astray when clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

The problem is that when the click happens, the pagination of something shifts.When I click on the 3rd page, the pagination should have the value 41-51, but for some reason it jumps to 23-33.

[image]

EpisodePageComponent

```
export class EpisodePageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  episodes: IEpisode[];
  page: number = 1;
  info: IInfo

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handlePage();
  }

  handlePage(event?: PageEvent) {
    if (event) {
      this.page = event.pageIndex + 1
    }

    this._setQueryPage();
    this._loadEpisodes();
  }

  _loadEpisodes(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({episode}) => {
      this.episodes = episode.results;
      this.info = episode.info;
    })
  }

  _setQueryPage(): void {
    const queryParams: Params = {page: this.page};
    this.router.navigate([], {
      relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
      queryParams,
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    })
  }
}
```

episode-page.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="episodes.length > 0">
  <mat-paginator class="pagination"
    (page)="handlePage($event)"
    [length]="info.count"
    [pageSize]="episodes.length"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[20]"
    aria-label="Select page">
  </mat-paginator>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: are you trying to load more episode every right arrow click?

Comment: A total of 51 episodes, but somehow when it reaches the last page, it jumps to 23-33

Comment: Just looking at the available code, all the episodes should already loaded. There's no need to load it again as the pagination changes. Just remove `(page)="handlePage($event)"`

Comment: when i take it off it really works but then nothing changes

Comment: try this ? `(page)="pageEvent = handlePage($event)"`

Comment: Unresolved variable or type pageEvent

Comment: @vasdasdasda your problem is that page size is dynamic -  `[pageSize]="episodes.length"` . Since it's dynamic, the last page brings back 11 items and the page size changes from 20 to 11. Hence you see page 3 when page size is 11. These are items 23-33. Change it to be e.g. `pageSize="20"` and see the behavior.